# What is the difference between UPD78130 and UPD78130G?

Tags: digital-logic

I have a Korg DW 6000 that's displaying all eights on the LEDs. I've checked the reset circuit and also decoders 11 and 12. I think the problem is the CPU on the KLM-653 board.

I've tried to check the logic using both the schematic and the datasheet, but the only thing that stands out is that the WR line is showing to be high when, unless I'm misreading the description for that pin, it should be low other than during reset or memory/read write operations.

If anyone is familiar with these or has any thoughts about what else to check, I'd appreciate any feedback. I can post a schematic if needed.

Also, a side question but on topic is that the schematic lists the CPU's as UPD-7810 or (UPD7811 161-36) for the KLM-653 board and UPD-78130G or (UPD-7811 161-36) for the KLM-654 board. On paper these chips seem to be identical. What's the difference between these chips, specifically UPD78130 vs UPD7830G?

Comment: WR is an active low pin so should normally be high (inactive), and only going low during occasional write cycles.

Comment: There is a typo in the numbers either in the heading our in your last sentence of the text.

Answer (score 0):

It has been over 40 years since I worked with one of those. They were released as part of the Upd7800 family. If you look at the architecture it is **similar to** the upd790 or Z80.  The uPD7811 has internal ROM and the uPD7810 has no internal ROM. You can use the uPD7811 inplace of the uPD7810 by disabling the internal ROM. If my memory is correct this was originally a custom by NEC for a Japanese printer manufacturer.

You ask the difference between 78130 and 78130G. They should be the same. The 'G' probably is a package definition. I do not know for sure but I believe they are ROM based parts which would make them different. I do not have the data sheets to be sure.

Comment: Do you know what the difference between 78130 and 78130G is? The schematic details the CPU on the KLM-654 board to be 78130G and the KLM-653 board to be 78130.